# Enter key on ASUS Taichi is intermitent

Tags: laptop, keyboard, asus-laptop

My girlfriend recently got an ASUS Taichi.  I have been setting it up and putting programs on it for the last day, and I have noticed that sometimes the enter key just doesn't work.  It is not just the physical key, but the problem also occurs when using the touchscreen keyboard.  Every time I notice this it seems to go away after 75 seconds or so, but that is more then long enough to be a very large inconvenience.

Comment: At the time(s) that the enter key won't work, will any other key work?

Comment: Yes, all other keys seem to work, at least the ones I have tried.  Absolutely nothing else seems to be affected except for the enter key... Hmmm.